# yolov4 bounding box ext_output

Tags: object-detection, yolo, bounding-box, yolov4

Im using the ext_output parameter in yolov4 to get the coordinates of the bounding box in my image. Everything works fine, but im not sure how to reach this coordinates to crop the img. For example the output looks like that:

```html
dog: 99%    (left_x:   62   top_y:  261   width:  138   height:   89)
person: 99% (left_x:  191   top_y:   93   width:   82   height:  285)
horse: 79%  (left_x:  401   top_y:  131   width:  203   height:  207)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would use test command like this:

```
./darknet detector test /your/path/obj.data /your/path/yolov4-obj.cfg /your/path/yolov4-obj_best.weights -dont_show -ext_output -save_labels < /your/path/test.txt > /your/path/result.txt
```

Then you would be able to see resulting bounding boxes in `result.txt` file. Then, you could search for the name of detected object in the text file with similar idea of this:

```
with open('result.txt') as f:
objList = []
abc = f.readlines()
for k in range(len(abc)):
    if abc[k].startswith("yourObject"):
        objList.append(abc[k])
```

and then you could reach its bonding box coordinates with search string in `objList`. (Assuming your object is detected by the model)